# 'datetime.time' has no 'mktime'

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a datetime object to a UNIX timestamp (preferably in milliseconds, though I wouldn't mind with and without).

Mktime seems to be the method that usually gets it, however I keep getting the error:

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'mktime'.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I keep going round in circles!

Comment: Standard date time object.

I'm using this code:

..
time.mktime(datetimeobject.timetuple())
..
As well as a lot of variation.

Comment: @malcmcmul: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please edit the question itself.

Comment: @malcmcmul: Please include ALL the code.  You show `time.mktime(...)`.  Does this mean you have a variable named `time`?  `time` is a module name, so it's a bad choice for a variable name if you have `import time`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you have done

```
from datetime import datetime, time
```

instead of

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
```

so that the object called `time` is actually coming from the datetime module, not the time module.

Comment: thanks a lot. just another question though.
how do i include milliseconds to the return timestamp?

Comment: `time.mktime(datetimeobject.timetuple()) + datetimeobject.microsecond/1000000.0`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, even using the above answer, I still got the same error message.

I´ve solved my problem using

```
>>>>from time import mktime as mktime
>>>>today = mktime(2012, 12, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I don't know the why, but, it only worked using the alias (as mktime)... can somebody tell me the reason ...

Comment: you should post that as a new questions.