# 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, datetime

Users in my app have date_joined fields that are in this format: `2014-12-14 14:46:43.379518+00:00`

In order to pass this datetime along to Intercom.io, it must be a UNIX timestamp like this: `1426020706` (this is not the same time, just an example).

I've tried several methods I've read here on Stack Overflow (nothing in this question has the same starting time format: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python)), but none have worked. mktime() seemed promising, but I got "'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'mktime'."

I just tried this:

```
import time
import dateutil.parser
import member.models import Member

member = Member.objects.get(email="aspeksnijder@outlook.com")
date_joined = member.date_joined
dt = dateutil.parser.parse(date_joined)
print int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
```

It returned "'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'read'". How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287598/datetime-time-has-no-mktime

Comment: It looks like member.date_joined is already a datetime object, and there's no need to parse it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have an aware datetime object. If you *print* it then it looks like:

```
2014-12-14 14:46:43.379518+00:00
```

To be sure `print(repr(date_joined))`.

[Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python) shows several ways how you could get the timestamp e.g.,

```
timestamp = date_joined.timestamp() # in Python 3.3+
```

Or on older Python versions:

```
from datetime import datetime

# local time = utc time + utc offset
utc_naive = date_joined.replace(tzinfo=None) - date_joined.utcoffset()
timestamp = (utc_naive - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Note: `timestamp = calendar.timegm(date_joined.utctimetuple())` would also work in your case but it may return a wrong result *silently* if you pass it a naive datetime object that represents local time by mistake.

If your input is a time string then [convert the time string into a datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279) first.

Answer (score 3):

What about (using the [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) and [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) packages):

```
import dateutil.parser
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import pytz

def str2ts(s):
    ''' Turns a string into a non-naive datetime object, then get the timestamp '''
    # However you get from your string to datetime.datetime object
    dt = dateutil.parser.parse(s)           # String to non-naive datetime
    dt = pytz.utc.normalize(dt)             # Normalize datetime to UTC
    ts = calendar.timegm(dt.timetuple())    # Convert UTC datetime to UTC timestamp
    return int(ts)

def ts2str(ts):
    '''Convert a UTC timestamp into a UTC datetime, then format it to a string'''
    dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)      # Convert a UTC timestamp to a naive datetime object
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)        # Convert naive datetime to non-naive
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

Which we can test with:

```
# A list of strings corresponding to the same time, with different timezone offsets
ss = [
    '2014-12-14 14:46:43.379518+00:00',
    '2014-12-14 15:46:43.379518+01:00',
    '2014-12-14 16:46:43.379518+02:00',
    '2014-12-14 17:46:43.379518+03:00',
]    

for s in ss:
    ts = str2ts(s)
    s2 = ts2str(ts)

    print ts, s2
```

Output:

```
1418568403 2014-12-14 14:46:43.000000+0000
1418568403 2014-12-14 14:46:43.000000+0000
1418568403 2014-12-14 14:46:43.000000+0000
1418568403 2014-12-14 14:46:43.000000+0000
```

These output all the same timestamps, and "verification" formatted strings.

Comment: I tried that and got this: "AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: It looks like doing "date_joined = str(member.date_joined)" worked.

Comment: @jedwards the parse function cannot handle timezones

Comment: @heinst `dateutil.parser.parse` handles timezones fine (see: `print(repr(dateutil.parser.parse(<string with timezone>)))`) -- however, I assumed that all the strings would be in UTC -- I'll update my answer with a more robust solution.

Comment: Updated with code that will correctly handle strings with different timezone offsets.

Comment: @MichelleGlauser: do not convert `date_joined` to string if you want to get the timestamp. The error message says that you already have `datetime` object. You do not need `dateutil.parser.parse` here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following Python 3 code:

```
import time, datetime
print(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-12-14 14:46:43.379518", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timetuple()))
```

which prints:

```
1418568403.0
```

Comment: downvote: `mktime()` is wrong unless the local timezone is utc (notice: `+00:00` in the question)

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem when I used input from Django's `DateField`, which is displayed in a form of `XXXX-YY-ZZ`: `parse(django_datefield)` causes the exception.

The solution: use `str(django_datefield)`.

```
parse(str(django_datefield))
```

Comment: downvote. Why would you convert a `datetime` object into a string only to parse it back?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I want to highlight that the answer is likely what @Peter said in his comment:

```
It looks like member.date_joined is already a datetime object, and there's no need to parse it. – Peter Feb 25 '17 at 0:33
```

So-- your model probably already parses into a datetime.datetime object for you.